# Chrome Extension Content Script Not Injecting After 302 Redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-chrome-extension

The chrome content script is not injecting after a page I load throws a 302 redirect to a sign in landing page. If I refresh the sign in landing page, the content script injects successfully. I believe this is caused by the 302 redirect and when/how Chrome injects content scripts.

Everything is working great with the extension. The page that I connect to and the page that is redirected to are both listed in the matches. I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find anything related to this.

Does anyone know of a way to ensure the content script does inject without refreshing the page (e.g. webRequest, manifest property, etc.)?

EDIT:

As per wOxxOm's link to the bug report for chrome, here is that pages information.

http://crbug.com/26804

> Chrome Version       : 4.0.221.6 (Official Build 28091)
>
> URLs (if applicable) : N/A Other browsers tested: Add OK or FAIL after other
> browsers where you have tested this issue:
>
> Safari 4:
>
> Firefox 3.x:
>
> IE7:
>
> IE 8:
>
> What steps will reproduce the problem?
>
> 1. Create an extension that uses a content script
> 2. Run chrome with extension loaded
> 3. Access URL (include in the match pattern).  The URL must cause 302  redirect, then a 401, then a 302 back to the originally requested URL.
>
> (ALL URL's invovlved in this DO MATCH the pattern.)
>
> What is the expected result?
>
> Content script fired
>
> What happens instead?
>
> Content script never runs on the URL that is
> involved in the redirects

No fix or work around noted though. So any help with such a thing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like https://crbug.com/26804. Can you share the URL and the extension in that bug report so that the developers have a way to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Jesus. Reported back in '09 and still a valid bug. Unfortunately I could not share the url. It would be pointless to share anyway, as the url is behind a firewall. But the bug report is entirely accurate as to what is happening. I hope someone can think of a work around, as I have no idea what I could do.

Comment: Supposedly you can do it using [webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) or [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API and inject the content script with chrome.tabs.executeScript. I wish I had an URL for tests though...

Comment: It would dramatically increase the chance for you to get an answer if you included a [mcve]. Having a known URL which exhibits the problem consistently would at least enable us to determine which events are fired to know what to look for in writing a work-around.